# AI/machine-learning based warning system for stock trading?

Tags: machine-learning, finance, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for an AI/machine-learning based tool that will provide automated stock trading alerts.

Required features:

- It should be easy to set up, requiring no more than a list of ticker symbols in the most basic case. Advanced users can configure more per-asset parameters. I should not have to write my own or spend 4 weeks on a "learning curve" just to get started. It's almost 2020, and I expect the pace of technology to keep up with the year.
- it will watch price and technical indicators in real-time for anything alarming that indicates an incoming stock surge or plunge.
- In case of a surge or plunge, it will estimate the top or bottom in seconds and warn the user accordingly
- The tool should pull in news relevant to each stock in real-time by searching a configurable list of financial news aggregators.
- It needs to be partially news-cycle aware. If options expiration is coming up, it should have a warning indicating upcoming expiration and how it might affect stocks it's watching. If there's an upcoming ex-dividend, it needs to know about that as well. Incoming earnings or other reports from company or industry? Pull those in for the user to read.
- IMPORTANT: The tool will only be used for trading advice, NOT automated trading. Keeping a human in the loop at all times prevents a glitch from making a bunch of bad trades and ruining its linked account.

Comment: Are you looking for opensource/free or paid tool?

Comment: Either. Gratis (free) is always preferred but I would pay for this.